# php post form max input vars strange behaviour

Tags: ckeditor

I am posting only 2 variables. If I do a direct POST using the form below it works.

```
<form action="http://someapi/post_html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" name="name" >
   <textarea name="htmltemplate"> a html template of  3000 characters 
   </textarea>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I use ajax to post the data I actually get a response back from the server `max_input_vars limit of 1000 exceeded`. How is it possible when I'm only sending 2 variables using ajax that I get that message?

I also tried using curl to do a POST and ended up receiving the same message.

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit',function() {
    var formData = $('form.ajax').serialize();
    formData +=  CKEDITOR.instances.textboxwyswygs.getData();

    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://someapi/post_html",
        method:"POST",
        data: formData,
        success: function(response){
             console.log(response);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: remove action in form

Comment: Can you please print the formData before sending to ajax?

Comment: `max_input_vars limit` is NOT a size but count of INPUT variables (http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars). You doing something wrong with `formData` preparation.

Answer (score 0):

Your `formData` looks broken - `serialize()` returns a JSON string and the CKEditor `getData()` returns a string of HTML.

Try this: synchronize the CKEditor value into the form before calling serialize and then your JSON will be correct. Try to `console.log(formData)` to check the formData before sending. So submitting the form without the syncrhonziation doesn't actually send the CKE content at all. This should be checked server-side to see what input it is getting.

Also the value of the ajax functions `data` member is expected to be correct JSON and servers might handle it in weird ways.

---

Other issues: `$('form.ajax')` does not actually target your HTML. Is this a correct example?

The `event` variable looks undefined, try naming it `e` and adding it as a parameter to `.on('submit',function(e){..}`.

You don't show the code where you actually replace the textarea with a CKEditor, it would be useful to see.

Comment: yeah this was just portions of code, i found out that ckeditor is doing some strange things when you use CKEDITOR.instances.textboxwyswygs.getData();   to get data from text area 

also i have to submit twice for the ajax to work 
on first submit  only hafl of email template is saved always and than on second submit an full template is saved ...it seems like a bug in ck editor

Comment: @user3548161 I very much doubt that it's a bug in CKE. That code you have is very broken and doesn't make any sene. How do you synchronize the CKE? Is the CKE attached to the textarea even? There is so much missing from your question that it's very hard to say anything conclusive, but the formData is guaranteed to be broken there.

Comment: @user3548161 oh and posting portions of code is good practice, but the portion should be a working example of the issue you are facing :)